# Finding amplitude of oscillation without graph

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I have the question "A mass at the end of a spring oscillates with a period of 2.8s. The maximum displacement of the mass from its equilibrium position is 16cm.
What is the amplitude of the oscillations ?"

I'm not sure how to find the amplitude as there is no graph given. Is there an equation to find this ?

Comment: Are you aware of the definition of `amplitude`?

Comment: Yes it is the maximum displacement of points on a wave measured from the equilibrium position. So is the answer 0.16 m ?

Comment: Yes, the answer is just $0.16$m.

Answer (score 0):

Amplitude is the maximum displacement of points on a wave measured from the equilibrium position. The answer 0.16 m.